# Python NtQueryDirectoryFile (File information structure)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, ntdll, nt-native-api

I've written a simple (test) script to list files in a selected directory. Not using `FindFirstFile`;
only native API.
When I execute the script and watch, Win32API monitor tells me STATUS_SUCCESS.
My File Information buffer is `c_buffer(1024)`, not using a Unicode buffer to see the raw data.

So after call `NtQueryDirectoryFile` all is ok.
When I write `c_buffer` in raw mode to console to see the files in the directory, the output is not structured.
I created a FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION structure but either it does not work Windows 7 X86 or there's a problem in my code.

My Question:
Please tell me which FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION structure use on Windows 7 X86 or any variants

```
from ctypes import *

hFile = windll.kernel32.CreateFileW("C:\\a",0x80000000,0,0,3,0x02000000,0)

class Info(Union):
    _fields_ = [('STATUS',c_long),
                ('Pointer',c_ulong),]


class io_stat(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Stat',Info),
                ('Information',c_ulong),]


class FILE_OBJECT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('Next',c_ulong),
                ('FileIndex',c_ulong),
                ('ctime',c_longlong),
                ('lat',c_longlong),
                ('wtime',c_longlong),
                ('ch',c_longlong),
                ('Endogfile',c_longlong),
                ('allo',c_longlong),
                ('Fileattr',c_ulong),
                ('Filenalen',c_ulong),
                ('Filename',c_wchar * 2),]

b = io_stat()
a = c_buffer(1024)

windll.ntdll.NtQueryDirectoryFile(hFile,0,0,0,byref(b),byref(a),sizeof(a), 1,0,None,0)

print(a.raw)
```

Not optimized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NtQueryDirectoryFile` should be called in a loop until it returns `STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES`. If either the returned status is `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` or the status is successful (non-negative) with the status block `Information` as 0, then double the buffer size and try again. For each successful pass, copy the `FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION` records out of the buffer. Each record has to be sized to include the `FileName`. You've reached the end when the `Next` field is 0.

The following example subclasses `FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION` as a `DirEntry` class that has a `listbuf` class method to list the records in a queried buffer. It skips the "." and ".." entries. It uses this class in an `ntlistdir` function that lists the `DirEntry` records for a given directory via `NtQueryDirectoryFile`. It supports passing an open file descriptor as the `path` argument, which is like how `os.listdir` works on POSIX systems.

**ctypes definitions**

```
import os
import msvcrt
import ctypes

from ctypes import wintypes

ntdll = ctypes.WinDLL('ntdll')
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

def NtError(status):
    err = ntdll.RtlNtStatusToDosError(status)
    return ctypes.WinError(err)

NTSTATUS = wintypes.LONG
STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW = NTSTATUS(0x80000005).value
STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES = NTSTATUS(0x80000006).value
STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = NTSTATUS(0xC0000004).value

ERROR_DIRECTORY = 0x010B
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value
GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000
FILE_SHARE_READ = 1
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0x0010

FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS = wintypes.ULONG
FileDirectoryInformation = 1
FileBasicInformation = 4

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = wintypes.LPVOID
PIO_APC_ROUTINE = wintypes.LPVOID
ULONG_PTR = wintypes.WPARAM

class UNICODE_STRING(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('Length',        wintypes.USHORT),
                ('MaximumLength', wintypes.USHORT),
                ('Buffer',        wintypes.LPWSTR))

PUNICODE_STRING = ctypes.POINTER(UNICODE_STRING)

class IO_STATUS_BLOCK(ctypes.Structure):
    class _STATUS(ctypes.Union):
        _fields_ = (('Status',  NTSTATUS),
                    ('Pointer', wintypes.LPVOID))
    _anonymous_ = '_Status',
    _fields_ = (('_Status',     _STATUS),
                ('Information', ULONG_PTR))

PIO_STATUS_BLOCK = ctypes.POINTER(IO_STATUS_BLOCK)

ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile.restype = NTSTATUS
ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # In  FileHandle
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,       # Out IoStatusBlock
    wintypes.LPVOID,        # Out FileInformation
    wintypes.ULONG,         # In  Length
    FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS) # In  FileInformationClass

ntdll.NtQueryDirectoryFile.restype = NTSTATUS
ntdll.NtQueryDirectoryFile.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # In     FileHandle
    wintypes.HANDLE,        # In_opt Event
    PIO_APC_ROUTINE,        # In_opt ApcRoutine
    wintypes.LPVOID,        # In_opt ApcContext
    PIO_STATUS_BLOCK,       # Out    IoStatusBlock
    wintypes.LPVOID,        # Out    FileInformation
    wintypes.ULONG,         # In     Length
    FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS, # In     FileInformationClass
    wintypes.BOOLEAN,       # In     ReturnSingleEntry
    PUNICODE_STRING,        # In_opt FileName
    wintypes.BOOLEAN)       # In     RestartScan

kernel32.CreateFileW.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.CreateFileW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,      # In     lpFileName
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwDesiredAccess
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwShareMode
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, # In_opt lpSecurityAttributes
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwCreationDisposition
    wintypes.DWORD,        # In     dwFlagsAndAttributes
    wintypes.HANDLE)       # In_opt hTemplateFile

class FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('CreationTime',   wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('LastAccessTime', wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('LastWriteTime',  wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('ChangeTime',     wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('FileAttributes', wintypes.ULONG))

class FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('_Next',          wintypes.ULONG),
                ('FileIndex',      wintypes.ULONG),
                ('CreationTime',   wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('LastAccessTime', wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('LastWriteTime',  wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('ChangeTime',     wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('EndOfFile',      wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('AllocationSize', wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER),
                ('FileAttributes', wintypes.ULONG),
                ('FileNameLength', wintypes.ULONG),
                ('_FileName',      wintypes.WCHAR * 1))

    @property
    def FileName(self):
        addr = ctypes.addressof(self) + type(self)._FileName.offset
        size = self.FileNameLength // ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.WCHAR)
        return (wintypes.WCHAR * size).from_address(addr).value
```

**`DirEntry` and `ntlistdir`**

```
class DirEntry(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{} {!r}>'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.FileName)

    @classmethod
    def listbuf(cls, buf):
        result = []
        base_size = ctypes.sizeof(cls) - ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.WCHAR)
        offset = 0
        while True:
            fdi = cls.from_buffer(buf, offset)
            if fdi.FileNameLength and fdi.FileName not in ('.', '..'):
                cfdi = cls()
                size = base_size + fdi.FileNameLength
                ctypes.resize(cfdi, size)
                ctypes.memmove(ctypes.byref(cfdi), ctypes.byref(fdi), size)
                result.append(cfdi)
            if fdi._Next:
                offset += fdi._Next
            else:
                break
        return result

def isdir(path):
    if not isinstance(path, int):
        return os.path.isdir(path)
    try:
        hFile = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(path)
    except IOError:
        return False
    iosb = IO_STATUS_BLOCK()
    info = FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION()
    status = ntdll.NtQueryInformationFile(hFile, ctypes.byref(iosb),
                ctypes.byref(info), ctypes.sizeof(info),
                FileBasicInformation)
    return bool(status >= 0 and info.FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)

def ntlistdir(path=None):
    result = []

    if path is None:
        path = os.getcwd()

    if isinstance(path, int):
        close = False
        fd = path
        hFile = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(fd)
    else:
        close = True
        hFile = kernel32.CreateFileW(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ,
                    None, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, None)
        if hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
            raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
        fd = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(hFile, os.O_RDONLY)

    try:
        if not isdir(fd):
            raise ctypes.WinError(ERROR_DIRECTORY)
        iosb = IO_STATUS_BLOCK()
        info = (ctypes.c_char * 4096)()
        while True:
            status = ntdll.NtQueryDirectoryFile(hFile, None, None, None,
                        ctypes.byref(iosb), ctypes.byref(info),
                        ctypes.sizeof(info), FileDirectoryInformation,
                        False, None, False)
            if (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW or
                iosb.Information == 0 and status >= 0):
                info = (ctypes.c_char * (ctypes.sizeof(info) * 2))()
            elif status == STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES:
                break
            elif status >= 0:
                sublist = DirEntry.listbuf(info)
                result.extend(sublist)
            else:
                raise NtError(status)
    finally:
        if close:
            os.close(fd)

    return result
```

**Example**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    for entry in ntlistdir(sys.exec_prefix):
        print(entry)
```

**Output:**

```
<DirEntry 'DLLs'>
<DirEntry 'include'>
<DirEntry 'Lib'>
<DirEntry 'libs'>
<DirEntry 'LICENSE.txt'>
<DirEntry 'NEWS.txt'>
<DirEntry 'python.exe'>
<DirEntry 'python.pdb'>
<DirEntry 'python3.dll'>
<DirEntry 'python36.dll'>
<DirEntry 'python36.pdb'>
<DirEntry 'python36_d.dll'>
<DirEntry 'python36_d.pdb'>
<DirEntry 'python3_d.dll'>
<DirEntry 'pythonw.exe'>
<DirEntry 'pythonw.pdb'>
<DirEntry 'pythonw_d.exe'>
<DirEntry 'pythonw_d.pdb'>
<DirEntry 'python_d.exe'>
<DirEntry 'python_d.pdb'>
<DirEntry 'Scripts'>
<DirEntry 'tcl'>
<DirEntry 'Tools'>
<DirEntry 'vcruntime140.dll'>
```

Comment: :p Very thank you and sorry i can't reputation you because my rep<15 :D .But you answer is useful.Thx